# What would be the Latin equivalent of the English noun, "reflex"?

Tags: vocabulary

The English word "reflex" [comes from the late Latin word *reflexus*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/reflex#Etymology), *to bend back, turn away*. Is there a Latin noun equivalent to reflex in the modern sense? Classical is preferred, but any period is fine.

Comment: Which meaning of "reflex" are you looking for, specifically? I may be biased as a linguist but my first thought was that you were looking for a word for "descendant" before I thought of the other meaning "instinctive response".

Comment: In this case I'm thinking of an instinctive response, the kind you do in an almost automated manner.